# regex: tokenizing <opening><scotch-game><fried-liver-attack>

Tags: java, regex

How can I get individual tokens of the the `<opening><scotch-game><fried-liver-attack>` string using regex. So the output should be 3 following strings:

1. opening
2. scotch-game
3. fried-liver-attack

EDIT:

This is not a proper xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pangea, you are trying to do with regex? This code will do what you want.

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<([^>]*?)>");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

The pattern itself is very simple: `<([^>]*?)>`

We match an opening `<`, then the parentheses lazily capture into Group 1 any number of characters that are not a closing brace with `[^>]*?` Finally for good measure we match a closing `>` to make sure we have a full token.

The Java code just builds a list with all our Group 1 captures, which is what you want.

Please note that this will not gracefully handle `<nested <tokens>>`. That would be another discussion.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple.

```
    String str = "<opening><scotch-game><fried-liver-attack>";
    String[] tokens = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1).split("><");
```

Comment: Braj-I am checking if we can do this with regex. I know that I can find a solution using split and string functions. +1 for trying though

Comment: OK Let me provide it for you.

Comment: `String.split()` takes regex. `"><"` is a regex pattern.

Comment: Sure. I am seeing if there is a a pattern for tokenizing a delemited text in a generic way...without requiring for me to remove the start and end

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
public class PracticeOne 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String s="<opening><scotch-game><fried-liver-attack>";
    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(s,"<>");
    ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
    while(st.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String element=(String)st.nextElement();
        if(!element.equals(""))
            al.add(element);
    }
    System.out.println(al);
}
}
```